# I am trying to figure how to do proper error handling with boto3

Tags: python, jenkins, ansible, devops, boto3

I'm trying to create dns entries using ansible but failing with below error.

```
/tmp/ansible_route53_payload_oyijp456/ansible_route53_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/module_utils/cloud.py", line 144, in retry_func
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 960, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInput: An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: Invalid request: Missing field 'SetIdentifier' in Change with [Action=UPSERT, Name=test.xdp.comcast.net., Type=A, SetIdentifier=null]
fatal: [xdpeksbuild-e1a-02-devops.xdp.comcast.net]: FAILED! => {
    "boto3_version": "1.26.62",
    "botocore_version": "1.29.100",
    "changed": false,
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidInput",
        "message": "Invalid request: Missing field 'SetIdentifier' in Change with [Action=UPSERT, Name=test.xdp.comcast.net., Type=A, SetIdentifier=null]
```

Example:

```yaml
- name: "Create/update dns record for green env"
  route53:
      state: present
      zone: ""
      record: ""
      type: A
      value: ""
      identifier: "east"
      region: "east"
      overwrite: yes
      alias: True
      alias_hosted_zone_id: ""
```

I see issue with python3 but same working with python2.7.

Answer (score 0):

The Ansible playbook you provided is attempting to create DNS records using the module Route53. However, the error message indicates that a required field, 'SetIdentifier,' is missing in the change request.

you need to provide a value for the 'SetIdentifier' field.

```
- name: Create/update DNS record for green env
  route53:
    state: present
    zone: "<zone_name>"
    record: "<record_name>"
    type: A
    value: "<IP_address>"
    set_identifier: "east"  # Add SetIdentifier field with a value
    region: "east"
    overwrite: yes
    alias: True
    alias_hosted_zone_id: "<alias_hosted_zone_id>"
```

Comment: thank you gaurav. Seeing different error after updating playbook.
msg": "Unsupported parameters for (route53) module: set_identifier. Supported parameters include: security_token (access_token, aws_security_token), health_check, aws_ca_bundle, weight, vpc_id, debug_botocore_endpoint_logs, profile (aws_profile), aws_access_key (access_key, ec2_access_key), zone, alias_evaluate_target_health, region, hosted_zone_id, value, alias_hosted_zone_id, wait_timeout, type, validate_certs, retry_interval, state (command), record, ttl, ec2_url